# How to implement logging mechanism for React.js application on AWS CloudWatch

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a React.js app that is deployed with AWS Amplify. What I want is to log errors and etc. to CloudWatch, however, after researching on the internet, I couldn't find a proper way to do it so.

I have tried the Amplify SDK and used a utility called [Logger](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/logger/q/platform/js)

However, it seems like this utility only helps to log things in the browser console, rather than logging it to the [Access Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/access-logs.html) that is coming with Amplify. What is the most convenient way to log things in such a scenario? Thanks.